# How to run a shell command inside AWK that takes AWK variables as the input?

Tags: regex, awk

My package manager has a option `--dry-run` or `-n` that shows what packages will be installed when I do a update `-u`.

It outputs in the following format `<pkgver> <action> <arch> <repository> <installedsize> <downloadsize>`,

```
~ $ xbps-install -un | head -n 5
MesaLib-devel-20.1.4_1 update x86_64 https://alpha.de.repo.voidlinux.org/current 148212 35909
amdvlk-2020.Q3.2_1 update x86_64 https://alpha.de.repo.voidlinux.org/current 53003388 17077076
audacious-4.0.5_1 configure x86_64 https://alpha.de.repo.voidlinux.org/current 2016807 578996
libwavpack-5.3.0_1 configure x86_64 https://alpha.de.repo.voidlinux.org/current 174280 86184
libfluidsynth-2.1.3_1 configure x86_64 https://alpha.de.repo.voidlinux.org/current 448560 216298
```

I want to know only two things, the packages that are bigger than a MiB. The download size is in column 5, so, I did the following to get in human readable format, filter through grep and pretty print.

```
~ $ xbps-install -un | numfmt --field=5 --to=si | grep -P '\d+M' | awk '{printf("%30s%7s\n",$1,$5);}' | head -n 5
        amdvlk-2020.Q3.2_1    54M
         audacious-4.0.5_1   2.1M
 audacious-plugins-4.0.5_1   6.2M
           openvdb-7.0.0_1   9.2M
          alembic-1.7.13_1   3.0M
```

This works great. I want to make it shorter. I know has awk (mine is gawk) has a inbuilt PCRE, so I can get rid of grep. But when I try this, I get nothing.

```
   ~ $ xbps-install -un | numfmt --field=5 --to=si | awk '$5==/\d+M/ {printf("%30s%7s\n",$1,$5);}'
```

But awk throws me an error saying,

```
   awk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\d' is not a known regexp operator
```

I thought gawk supported PCRE, but apparently it doesn't. So, I replace `\d+` with `[0..9]+`. I get no error, but no output. Please help fix the error. Is there a way to run a command inside AWK? Something like this

```
   ~ $ xbps-install -un | awk '$5>1024 { print $1 `numfmt --to=si $5`; }
```

Is this even possible? Even in Perl/PHP?

EDIT: I'm sorry I asked the question in a wrong way. My main question was if there is a way to expand shell commands in AWK with AWK variables. For example, in bash shell commands can be expanded as below,

```
   ~ $ file `which python`
   ~ $ file $(which python)
   ~ $ file (which python)       # in fish
```

Similarly, I want to `numfmt` a awk variable, `$5` like `numfmt --to=iec $5`. So, I was wondering if I can do something like

```
   ~ $ xbps-install -un | awk '$5>1024 { print $1 `numfmt --to=si $5`; }
```

Comment: In your final code, you're testing `$5>1024`. That perfect. If you really need "human readable form", can't you just `print $1 int($5/1024)"M"`? And in any case, very nice question, thanks for including small(ish) sample data and required outputs! Good luck.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Awk never supported PCRE

Comment: This solution is so simple and clever, I never thought of it. Thanks. But you know a way to expand shell commands like `$(which python)` in bash and `(which python)` in fish, inside awk that takes awk variables?

Comment: @SegFault01: What is your expected output? You don't have to use shell commands for your use case (from my understanding of the que)

Comment: For this case, I don't but my question is more general. For any shell command can the expansion be done inside AWK that in AWK variables and if yes, how?

Comment: The portable replacement for `\d` would be `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]`, not `[0..9]`. The latter means the characters `0`, `.`, and `9`, not the set of digits.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you. I was wondering why `[0..9]+` wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Your `awk` just needs to be written as below. And `\d` is a PCRE digit pattern which is not/never supported in GNU Awk. Pipe the output of `numfmt` to below

```
awk '$5 ~ /M$/{ printf("%30s%7s\n", $1, $5) }'
```

which means, match those columns in `$5` whose last character ends with an `M` which would be the converted SI units in `MB`

The pattern below is wrong, because the `==` brings in literal string "equality" check in Awk, which you have intermingled with an incorrect PCRE construct.

```
awk '$5==/\d+M/'
```

Also the range expressions need to be written as `[0-9]` and not `[0..9]`.

---

For the updated question, for which OP wants to use `numfmt` inside `awk`, for which I don't see a reason as they can very well pipe the output of `numfmt` to `awk`.

If you want to run the `numfmt` command inside `awk`, you can use the `getline` function in `awk`

```
awk '$5 > 1024 { cmd = "numfmt --to=si " $5; print $1, ((cmd | getline res)>0)? res : $5; close(cmd) }'
```

This approach is not needed as your original `cmd | numfmt | awk` approach is very well valid.

Comment: What would be the correct way to match columns to a regex? `$5~/\d+M/`? But awk doesn't support PCRE. `$5~[0..9]+M` doesn't work. Also, this answer doesn't address my question, if I can run a shell command inside AWK that takes AWK argument?

Comment: @SegFault01: What is your expectation? Isn't your problem to list entries containing `M`? in `$5` after converstion to SI? If not can you explain a bit more?. Doesn't `xbps-install -un | numfmt --field=5 --to=si | awk '$5 ~ /M$/{ printf("%30s%7s\n", $1, $5) }'` get the right result?

Comment: Yes, this new edit is what I wanted to know. And yes, this is more cumbersome. The other approach was better. Thanks.

Comment: You should really use `cmd = "numfmt --to=si \047" $5 "\047"` so you're passing the value of `$5` to the shell as a literal string rather than unquoted for globbing, execution (consider if the value of `$5` was `$(do_bad_thing)`), word splitting, file name expansion, etc. (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).